# jQuery - Delete a list item with a backspace keypress event?

Tags: jquery

I would like to be able to click on a list item and then hit the backspace key to delete it. How would I do this with jQuery?

```
$('<li>Click Me</li>')
.appendTo('#list')
.click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('delete');
   $(this).focus(); // doesn't seem to do anything maybe??
})
.keypress(function(e){
    // this event handler doesn't fire
    var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (key === 8) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('delete'))
            $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Here's my jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/prRVc/

Looks like I can't attach a keypress event to a list item.

Comment: You can't give a list item focus. What you need to do is bind that keypress event to something that *can* gain focus, like the window.

Comment: To be a little more real-world, I'm building a tag input similar to the tag input in Stack Exchange. There is a text input. I add the delete class to the last tag in the list after the user hits the backspace key and there's nothing in the text field. I also want to be able to click on a tag and hit the backspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to try having the key handler on the document level. Also, it's safer to use 'keydown' instead of 'keypress'. Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/DwX4e/

```
$('<li>Click Me</li>')
.appendTo('#list')
.click(function(){
   $(this).addClass('delete');
   $(this).focus();
})

$(document).on('keydown', function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 8){
       $('li.delete').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the same answer as @Akhil Sekharan. The only addition I made is to return false when the keycode is handled, and that is only done IF a list element with that class was found. If you don't return false, the browser goes back one history item.

Comment: I made your answer the correct one because you can't use keypress for the document... you have to use keydown. Chrome doesn't recognize $(document).keypress()... I assume other browsers don't either, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use focus on the list element. You will get nothing :) 
Try to use another solution, create separate handler for document keypress and process lists with "delete" class:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    var key = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (key === 8) {
        $('li.delete').remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think document don't capture the backspace event

Comment: **Error:** Expected ')' and Missing semicolon at the end.

Comment: It needs to be $(document).keydown() not keypress() because keypress doesn't work on Chrome. Also, you want to return false if you handled the event so it doesn't propagate up. If it does propagate, the browser will interpret the backspace as going back 1 history item.